# ChecklistCombobox give the error in python

Tags: python

I am trying to use the ChecklistCombobox library in Python 3.12 but given the error at runtime

```
    cb = ChecklistCombobox(root,values=('1', '2', '3', '4'))
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'ChecklistCombobox' is not defined
```

I am new to python

please send the full code for combobox with the checkbox

Comment: cb = ChecklistCombobox(root,values=('1','2','3','4'))
cb.configure(checkbutton_height=2)        this is my code  and --   this is error                 cb = ChecklistCombobox(root,values=('1','2','3','4'))
cb.configure(checkbutton_height=2)

Comment: The error looks very self-explanatory. The `ChecklistCombobox` is not defined. You probably need to import it.

Answer (score 0):

Import the module before using it

```
import ChecklistCombobox
```

then you can use it

```
cb = ChecklistCombobox(root, values=('1', '2', '3', '4'))
```

If you get an error: `No module named ChecklistCombobox` install it  using pip

```
pip install ChecklistCombobox
```

Comment: Have you tried it? 1. `import ChecklistCombobox` doesn't work after you install `ChecklistCombobox`. 2. Even if it worked, your second code snippet wouldn't work because you are trying to call the module, not the class.

Answer (score 0):

So the error is in the package itself as mentioned by the author on the GitHub page of [ChecklistCombobox](https://github.com/hatfullr/ChecklistCombobox).

***Note by the Author:***

NOTE: You may need to also update your version even after installing for the first time. I am new to using PyPI, so I probably messed something up, but executing the following command after installing seems to work,

```
pip install --upgrade ChecklistCombobox
```

**Solution:**

So the solution I came up with, is to install the [checklistcombobox.py](https://github.com/hatfullr/ChecklistCombobox/blob/main/checklistcombobox.py) file and place it in the working directory, install the required imports for the `checklistcombobox` which includes the following:

```
pip install numpy
```

and then import the `checklistcombobox` in the main working file.

**Example:**

Here's the example that's working for me:

```
from checklistcombobox import ChecklistCombobox
from tkinter import *
master = Tk()

cb = ChecklistCombobox(master,values=('1','2','3','4'))
cb.configure(checkbutton_height=2)

master.mainloop()
```

**Conclusion:**

This should now work like a charm and should not give and error, avoid installing the package using pip as stated by the author her/himself.